# Diode in series with a resistor an in parallel with another resistor

Tags: resistors, diodes, ac

I have been facing some troubles with this problem.

My main concern is that if Vab = 0.7 (when V(t) > 0 V,) will the diode conduct? I think that isn't the case, but if that so I don´t know how to solve it.

I have to find the intervals when the diode will conduct and VR3(t).

I am sure that that when V(t) < 0.7 V the diode will not conduct so R1 and R3 will be in series. But how can I know when the diode will start to conduct? If R2 weren´t there I know how to solve the problem but unfortunaly thats not the case..
Here is the schematic of the problem:

R1 = 5 KOHM = R3 and R2 = 1KOHM. Vmax = 2V and f= 250 hz

[image]

Comment: If the supply is below the voltage that the diode is deemed to conduct then the diode will not conduct. What does "closed" mean BTW - closed as in a contact closing or closed as in some hydraulic valve blocking flow?

Comment: You might want to formulate a question. Also line out what you have already done and concluded.

Comment: You cannot solve 4 unknowns with only 0.7V given

Comment: Ok now you have 4 known values so solve using superposition, first without the diode, then state assumptions on diode choice of characteristics

Comment: Assume the diode conducts, then assume it doesn't, solve each. One will turn out to be consistent, the other won't. The consistent one is the correct solution.

Comment: "Slip" R3 to the left of R2, then apply Thevenin to v(t), R1, R3.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the diode is not conducting and replace it with an open circuit, or an ideal current source of 0A.

Determine the relationship between the input voltage and the voltage across the open circuit. Then, determine what value of input voltage will cause the diode to become forward biased.

Conversely, assume that diode is forward biased and determine what range of input voltages would cause the diode current to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest solved by folding R3 into V(t)/R1.  It is then comparatively easy to figure to figure out when D becomes conducting, and you can split the cases where it conducts and when not.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a diode clipper circuit? During the positive half cycle of the source there will the current flowing in R1 and R3 upto 0.7 volts from the source. After 0.7 volts the diode becomes a short circuit and the voltage across R1+diode(0.7v) will be across the R3 aswell. During the negative half cycle from the source the diode becomes reverse biased and current flows only through R1 and R3.